# Textarea value keeps incrementing from Select Option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `Textarea` and `Selection Tag`, I try to insert the value of selected option to my `Textarea` using js. but every time I change the option, the recent value was still there and a newly selected option is added. I want to remove a recently selected option every time I change an option. here is my code below

```
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('greet_box'); //Textarea
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('myShow'); //Select Tag

mydropdown.onchange = function(){
    jQuery('#greet_box').show();
        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value; //to appened
        //mytextbox.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like that

```
$("#myShow").change(function(){
    var mydropdown=$("#myShow").val();
    $("#greet_box").show();
    $("#greet_box").val(mydropdown);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset your `div` to empty.

```
 document.getElementById('greet_box').innerHTML = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljej0x5r/

The problem is here:

`mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value; //to appened`

Replace it with

`mytextbox.value = this.value;`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `mytextbox.value` from expression it will work.

Pen for this is http://codepen.io/sam83045/pen/NbXELO